# com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin, ionic4

I am working with ionic 4, everything was ok and i was able to build android apps until i had this error:

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.4,11.0.4]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew
>   :app:dependencies.

I tried to regenerate the platform folder but it didn't work. What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: It seems that the version of your `play-services-base` is `16.0.1` while other libraries request a `11.0.4` version.

Comment: but i can't find this plugin in my project, have you any idea where can i find such plugin. I know where to find cordova plugins but not this one.